# Is there a way to trigger a hook after the execution of a specific command in cypress

Tags: javascript, logging, cypress, hook

I am trying to monitor the state of the DOM after each call to cy.get and cy.find. I noticed that there are hooks in cypress but they only allow me to run before or after the test. I also looked at plugins, but I am not sure they would allow me to achieve what I am trying to do (I might be missing something though since I am a newbie in cypress).

So basically, my question is: Is it possible to trigger some kind of hook, that would be called every time a specific command is called by the cypress process?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

"Command" is a generic term for Cypress language feature that start with `cy.`.

Some, like `cy.get()` and `.find()` are querying commands and ***have no affect on the DOM***.

Others like `.click()` trigger an event in the app that may change the DOM, so you would use querying commands to see what has changed, or more precisely to test that what you ***expect*** to change have indeed changed.

Hooks you mention like beforeEach() and afterEach() are `mocha` hooks that intercept stages of the test, but they do not query the DOM.

There are also other events that will run some code after Cypress does something, but that's advanced stuff, not often used, and too broad to answer without a specific use-case.

---

If you want to look at inner workings of the Cypress queue, review this blog [Visualize Cypress Command Queue](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/visualize-cypress-command-queue/) and the accompanying video.

Comment: Thank for the answer. This is basically the idea to have a hook on a generic feature. I think querying commands are exactly what I am looking for. The idea is to record some information from the DOM and save them in a DB every time the test calls a query command. If the locator fails, then I can try to automatically fix it by relying on the gathered data from the previously passing queries. But I didn't find any way to intercept locators to collect these data.